# HTTP protocol deep understanding? how does it affect best practices in web programming?

Tags: http, https, httpwebrequest, http-headers

Understanding HTTP/TCP protocol is a bonus point for a web developer.

But does it really matter for a better client/server programmer?

core of the web is HTTP but my question is, **is it worth to read complete RFC or a book like
[HTTP: definitive guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565925090.do)?**

My assumption is that unless we are not too much involved in HTTP headers like streaming/file transfer/encoding over HTTP, it doesn't matter for normal applications.
Basic understanding of frame format and status codes should be sufficient i guess.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: It definitely helps. Consider optimizing page speed. http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/speed/page-speed/docs/overview.html is full of references to http.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will take you a couple of hours to read the RFC, and I think it's worth it because you will really be able to understand the details of what's happening. The HTTP protocol is rather simple but has some subtleties, for example what's the difference between sending a GET and a POST?

If you are serious about your craft, I recommend understanding it well.

Comment: thanks Francis, this encourages me to spend time on HTTP :)

Comment: I recommend spending the time on reading the new drafts, not RFC 2616.